# C++, i use the function at() from Vector, but i have problem

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, compiler-errors, overloading

[image: at problem in vector]

```
cannot convert '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::value_type' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>'} to 'const char*'gcc
```

sincerely i don't know why and how to correct this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

namespace anas 
{  
    void passwordGenerator() 
    {
        std::vector<std::string> PasswordString;

        std::string ElencoAlfabeto("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789");
        char CharAlfabeto[ElencoAlfabeto.length()];

        for (int Lettere_Create = 0; Lettere_Create < 8; Lettere_Create++)  
        {
            int             NumeroCarattere     = rand() % sizeof(CharAlfabeto);
            CharAlfabeto   [NumeroCarattere]    = ElencoAlfabeto[NumeroCarattere];
            
            PasswordString.push_back(CharAlfabeto[NumeroCarattere]); 
        }

        for (int Lettere_Scritte = 0; Lettere_Scritte < 8; Lettere_Scritte++)
        {
            printf (   PasswordString.at(Lettere_Scritte)    );
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    system("cls");
    std ::printf("the program is started... \n \n");
    anas::passwordGenerator();
}
```

the output should be a random 8 letter generator.

---

yes, this is my first time using `vector` ... here the article i use:[image: vector article doc]

when i put the mouse-cursor on the `at` , i see 1 overload, what is mean overload?
[image: overload error at]

Comment: please don't post images of text, code, errors. It's also a good ideea to point with a comment the line that triggers the error.

Comment: `char CharAlfabeto[ElencoAlfabeto.length()];` is illegal in standard C++ (without compiler extensions) since the size of `CharAlfabeto` must be known at compile time, not runtime

Comment: `char CharAlfabeto[ElencoAlfabeto.length()];` -- You `#include <vector>`,  but didn't use it for its intended purpose here.  This should be `std::vector<char> CharAlfabeto(ElencoAlfabeto.length());`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this line

```
printf (   PasswordString.at(Lettere_Scritte)    );
```

The function `printf` needs a `const char*` but your are giving it a `std::string`.

In addition to the type mismatch, you should never ever pass arbitrary data as the first parameter of `printf`, because it will try to interpret format codes.

If you really want to use `printf`, this will work:

```
printf( "%s", PasswordString.at(Lettere_Scritte).c_str() );
```

You can skip the format code decoding entirely using `puts`:

```
puts( PasswordString.at(Lettere_Scritte).c_str() );
```

Or you can use C++ iostreams, which know about `std::string` and don't need the `c_str()` call at all:

```
std::cout << PasswordString.at(Lettere_Scritte);
```

Comment: Side note: you have to be careful with `printf`. if you `printf( "%s", PasswordString.at(Lettere_Scritte) );` (note the `.cstr()` is missing) many compilers will not be able to warn you that you've made a mistake. Warning or no, the program will compile and may  exhibit strange behaviour at runtime.

Comment: `at()` returns a reference so there is no issue in this code, but generally I would avoid `c_str()` on a function return because if the function returns a prvalue you could easily end up with a dangling pointer.

Comment: @bolov: Passing the result of `c_str()` to printf is always ok, even if working with a temporary string.  Saving the result for use later is risky.